# Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entityType, null, parameters)

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

When I use "mywindow" like var is give my 'boll' answer

How can I make full screen of from entity?

```
var mywindow = Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entityType, null, parameters);
    mywindow .moveTo(0, 0);
    mywindow .resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` returns a bool not a window, the bool indicates if the call to `openEntityForm` was successful.

As described in the [Xrm.Utility Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72a66f93-92df-42b9-a8fd-b6125c7fe83b#BKMK_OpenEntityForm).

> **Return Value**: Boolean. True if the operation is successful, otherwise
>   false.

If you are looking at this bit (which is similar to your code above) of the same MSDN article I believe that the documentation is incorrect. Given the function returns a bool, I don't see how this is possible.

> **Open a new contact record, move it to the top left corner of the screen, and set the size of the window**
>
> ```
> var newWindow = Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("contact");
> newWindow.moveTo(0,0);
> newWindow.resizeTo(800,600);
> ```

You could:

1. On your first window use `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm(entityType, null, parameters);`
2. On your second window (that you just opened using `openEntityForm`) [add the following](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dynamicscrmonline/archive/2008/08/04/changing-the-window-size-for-crm-forms.aspx) `onLoad` event.

.

```
window.moveTo(0,0);
window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```